# .rmd file doesn't display properly under the source mode

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, rstudio

I have came across a rather unusual case when open my .rmd file after updating RStudio to version 2022.12.0 Build 353.

The code doesn't display properly under the **Source mode** (as picture 1 shows). Specifically, when scrolling the page up or down, code either disappear or doesn't show at all.

[image]
**Picture 1. Source mode**

[image]
**Picture 2. Visual mode**

However it works under the **Visual mode** (as picture 2 shows). In addition, rendering function under both modes works as before, so I have no trouble to generate report.

I suspect it is caused by this code fences, as the code display ok again after removing it:

````
```{css style_setting, echo=FALSE}

```
````

But in 7.1 Apply custom CSS of the [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html), it says:

> Alternatively, you can use a css code chunk to embed the CSS rules
> directly in your Rmd document, e.g.,
>
> We embed a `css` code chunk here.
>
> `{css, echo=FALSE} p {   font-size: 32px; }`  The chunk option
> echo = FALSE means the CSS code will not be displayed verbatim in the
> output, but a  tag containing the CSS code will be generated to
> the HTML output file.

As the Source mode is my preferred mode to work with, I am just wondering if any of you experienced similar issues under the new version of Rstudio? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays properly after replace the CSS code chunks from:

````
```{css style_setting, echo=FALSE}

```
````

to:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    
    </style>
```

While it's not consistent to other code chunks, it does work. Hopefully this is something Rstudio can fix in their next update.